# PHP switch trouble

Tags: php, switch-statement

> When U are sleepy and look at PHP switches after Ruby switches..

**UPDATE 3 (answer)**

*See problem below*. Its my mistake. All right:) . In PHP. With his dynamic typecasting ( false->(int)false->0: here I getting `0` equals to my`'>=17_<=20'`) and implict behaviour of construct `switch` in this specific case ( `switch( ZERO ) { case (true) break; case (false) break;}` ). This behaviour looks strange from side of strong typed languages. Thanks for all!!

SO,please,help!
I noticed a strange behavior of "checked" checkboxes on one page (choosing age groups). In database, if user checked `<16` - field `age` equals `0` (zero). And I began to see the logic for "checking". Found next:

```
   $item = 0; //!!!!!!!
   switch($item){
       case ($item<=16):
         $case = '<16';
         break;
       case ( ($item>=17) && ($item<=20)):
         $case = '>=17_<=20';
         break;
       case ( ($item>=21) && ($item<=25)):
         $case = '>=21_<=25';
         break;
   }
   echo $item.' '.$case.'<br/>';
```

OUTPUT

```
 0 >=17_<=20 // HOW???!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

*TEST*

```
  $range = range(-5,5);

  foreach($range as $item){

      switch($item){
          case ($item<=16):
                  $case = '<16';
                  break;
          case ( ($item>=17) && ($item<=20)):
                  $case = '>=17_<=20';
                  break;
          case ( ($item>=21) && ($item<=25)):
                  $case = '>=21_<=25';
                  break;
         }

         echo $item.' '.$case.'<br/>';
     }
```

// OUTPUT

```
 -5 <16
 -4 <16
 -3 <16
 -2 <16
 -1 <16
 0 >=17_<=20 // WHY???????!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 1 <16
 2 <16
 3 <16
 4 <16
 5 <16
```

http://3v4l.org/jbfng
Please,explain me, WHAT IS THIS?!

**UPDATE 1**
No,MEN, I am not crazy! All MUST works. Loop only for demonstration of this strange  behavior. If 0 (zero) < 16, `$case` MUST be equals `<16`. NO????????

**UPDATE 2**
Honestly, I don`t understand minuses. Ok.

```
    $item = 0;
    if (($item>=17) && ($item<=20)){ // false
        // never for  <17 & >20
    }

    item = 0;
    $checking  = (($item>=17) && ($item<=20)); // false
    if ($checkig){
        // never for  <17 & >20
    }

    item = 0;
    $checkig = (($item>=17) && ($item<=20)) ? true : false; // false
    if ($checkig){
         // never for  <17 & >20
    }      

    $item = 0;
    switch($item){
       case ( ($item>=17) && ($item<=20)): // false
          // never for  <17 & >20
          break;
    }
```

**All works fine**. Its only when **EQUALS ZERO**. Or You want to say,that OUTPUT(*Test2*) - its normal behaviour??? Thanks.

*TEST 2*

```
      $range = range(-5,47);
           //var_dump($range);

            foreach($range as $item){
                  switch($item){
                      case ($item<=16):
                            $case = '<16';
                            break;
                      case ( ($item>=17) && ($item<=20)):
                            $case = '>=17_<=20';
                            break;
                      case ( ($item>=21) && ($item<=25)):
                            $case = '>=21_<=25';
                            break;
                      case ( ($item>=26) && ($item<=35)):
                            $case = '>=26_<=35';
                            break;
                      case ( ($item>=36) && ($item<=45)):
                             $case = '>=36_<=45';
                             break;
                       case ( ($item>=46)):
                             $case = '>=46';
                             break;
                   }

                    echo $item.' '.$case.'<br/>';
           }
```

// OUTPUT

```
-5 <16
-4 <16
-3 <16
-2 <16
-1 <16
0 >=17_<=20 // WHY ?
1 <16
2 <16
3 <16
4 <16
5 <16
6 <16
7 <16
8 <16
9 <16
10 <16
11 <16
12 <16
13 <16
14 <16
15 <16
16 <16
17 >=17_<=20
18 >=17_<=20
19 >=17_<=20
20 >=17_<=20
21 >=21_<=25
22 >=21_<=25
23 >=21_<=25
24 >=21_<=25
25 >=21_<=25
26 >=26_<=35
27 >=26_<=35
28 >=26_<=35
29 >=26_<=35
30 >=26_<=35
31 >=26_<=35
32 >=26_<=35
33 >=26_<=35
34 >=26_<=35
35 >=26_<=35
36 >=36_<=45
37 >=36_<=45
38 >=36_<=45
39 >=36_<=45
40 >=36_<=45
41 >=36_<=45
42 >=36_<=45
43 >=36_<=45
44 >=36_<=45
45 >=36_<=45
46 >=46
47 >=46
```

Comment: your switch/case logic doesn't make much sense. You are using each `case` statement like an `if` statement, instead of using the switch.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a switch??? For the reason you are seeing what you are seeing http://3v4l.org/Z2EjY. Not strange. Stop abusing switch statements and you don't have this problem.

Comment: you mixed  `if` with `switch`

Comment: updated question,please look at

Comment: your update still shows that you don't understand how to use a swtich/case. Switch them to `if` statements like I have in my answer.

Comment: @Red Alert its has logic. Remove loop. I`ts simple switch->case->between.

Comment: updated question. If U have desire, can look at

Comment: There is nothing strange going on in your question. STOP ABUSING SWITCH STATEMENTS what happens is exactly what is to be expected when looking at how everything evaluates..

Comment: @PeeHaa  I thought that `switch` catching first statement (0<16) and stoped. Ok, thanks.

Comment: If anything you want to do `switch(true){` instead of `switch($item){` but reeeeally don't use a switch for tis.

Comment: @PeeHaa for me its - implicit behavior and hasn`t sense, if 0 < 16, `switch` must be breaking (its found `true`) in first `case`.But `switch` going below. Of course, next case return `false`,(int)false equals `zero` and I getting second case-block. Thanks! Never thought like that can be :) I thinking, in this specific case - typecasting is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the expression  `($item>=17) && ($item<=20)` evaluates to 0, as the value of `$item` is 0.
the switch-case statement will merely match the value of `$item` with `case` values.
So, your code, in first case is equivalent to

```
switch($item){
       case (1):
         $case = '<16';
         break;
       case ( 0):
         $case = '>=17_<=20';
         break;
       case ( 0):
         $case = '>=21_<=25';
         break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the error since "0" evaluates to false. Try this:

```
<?
  echo 0==(0>=17) && (0<=20)); //true
?>
```

This is because right side of the `==` evaluates to `false` and `0==false` is `true` so you hit that condition in your switch statement.

Switch statement compares the condition with the `switched` variable (in your case `item`) so it evaluates to true, and it enter the switch condition and breaks it there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be using a switch here. Use this:

```
$range = range(-5,5);

foreach($range as $item){
    if ($item<=16)
        $case = '<16';
    else if ( ($item>=17) && ($item<=20))
        $case = '>=17_<=20';
    else if( ($item>=21) && ($item<=25))
        $case = '>=21_<=25';


     echo $item.' '.$case.'<br/>';
 }
```